# Get data from table row

Tags: javascript

I have a table like code below.

```
<table id="tbldata" border="1">
    <tr> <th></th>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Price1</th>
        <th>Price2</th>           
    </tr>
    <tr> <td>
            <input class="btnedit" type="button" value="Edit" />
        </td>
        <td>Item1</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>99</td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I get data from table row.  I tried but it not work

```
    var item = $(this).prev().parent().prev().prev().text();
    var p1 = $(this).prev().parent().prev().text();
    var p2 = $(this).prev().parent().text();
```

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve]. What is `this`? What is the desired result?

Comment: Add your expected result format.and say if we can do any modification in this table html

Answer (score 0):

The table has an id of tblData, so you can use CSS selectors to get a reference to it in code. You can then use another query selector to get hold of the row you need, and then another to get the cell that you need. You can concatenate these into a single statement, but I've left them separate for clarity.

Use innerHTML to get the full content of the cell.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

<table id="tblData">
  <tr>
    <td>Id</td>
    <td>Count</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>54</td>
    <td><button onclick="getData(2);">Get</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>53</td>
    <td><button onclick="getData(3);">Get</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="output">
</div>

<script>
<!--
function getData(rowNumber){
    const table = document.getElementById("tblData");    
    const row1 = table.querySelector(`tr:nth-child(${rowNumber})`);
    const id1 = row1.querySelector("td:first-child");

    output.innerHTML = id1.innerHTML;
}
-->
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use as following with pure javascript:

```
const tableBody = document.querySelector("#tbldata").children[0].children;
for(let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < tableBody.length; rowIndex++){
    let row = tableBody[rowIndex].children;
    for(let colIndex = 0; colIndex < row.length; colIndex++){
        let col = row[colIndex];
        // you have the field and it's up to you to do with it whatever you want
        console.log(col.innerHTML);
    }
}
```